# Cannot map project to source control

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2010.
Recently I created a new project and I created a new source control folder. I checked in the project.
When I looked in source control explorer it says that the project Local Path is set to "Not mapped".
When I look inside the grayed out folder, I can see the code there.
I try to "Add Items to Folder", even though they are already there in Source Control Explorer.

I get an error message:

> The path ... is already mapped in workspace ...

[image: Screenshot of error message]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you have overlapping workspaces. a workspace can not overlap with another one. have a look in the other workspace and see where the overlap occurs. then delete / clean up so that you have a clean workspace / workspaces. it may be easier to add your new mapping to the old workspace and delete the new one